# How do I have a user select an already open excel file to import data to, and paste into the file they choose? (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, file, excel-formula

Amateur Coder here.

Currently, I have this Macro linked via button. The goal is the following:

A. Once button is pressed, prompts users to select an excel workbook to Import data to, I have the following code for this part:

```
  Sub select_file()

Dim FileSelect As FileDialog
Dim PathA As String

Set FileSelect = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With FileSelect
        .Title = "Please Select the Doc you want to import Data to"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "Confirm"
            If .Show = -1 Then
                PathA = .SelectedItems(1)
            Else
                End
            End If
    End With
    
Workbooks.Open Filename:=PathA

End Sub
```

B. Once selected, begins to copy and paste data in an absolute manner/HardCoded. (I know its discouraged, but cell will not change ever) OR hard write the following formula into the destination cell.  Please Assume F26 is from the destination document.

```
=IF(F26='[source.xlsm]Sheet1'!E10,'[Source.xlsm]Sheet1'!G10,"#REF")
```

How do I make Part B occur without recording it as a macro? Better yet, how do I make it plop that data into the destination?

Edit 1: The paste portion is me using the if function for verification.

Comment: FYI calling `End` is overkill if you just want to exit the sub at that point: use `Exit Sub` to avoid killing all state in your VB project (`End` will clear all global/static variables)

Comment: Sounds fun! But, Can we have a couple pictures for the visual learning in the back here.

Comment: @cameronCritchlow, how can i assist in visualizing?

Comment: Well first actually, are you trying to access specifically an open excel file?

Comment: Hey Cameron, The open workbook will simply be a destination for the source document. The open workbook will always be the same format. I got the source document 100% working, and I am having trouble pasting the contents to the already open excel worksheet, theres over a 150 unique cells to paste it to. The adjacent cell has the same name as the destination doc. I tried doing the if function in the destination document in VBA saying if one is equal to another (which it always is) how would i go about prompting a user to select an open excele sheet to paste into?

Comment: Just curious, so the Source.xlsm is the opened workbook with the sub? and what you want is : ask the user to choose the destination file ---> open the Excel user_chosen file  ---> ask the user to select a cell/range in the Source.xlsm to be copied ---> ask the user to select a cell/range in his chosen file (the destination file) to be pasted ---> then the sub do the copy-paste process based on those three user actions (choose destination file, choose range in the Source.xlsm to be copied, choose range in his chosen file to be pasted). Please CMIIW.

Comment: You wrote _" how would i go about prompting a user to select an open excele sheet to paste into? "_. Maybe try something like this `set UserSelection = application.inputbox("select a range", Type:=8)` ---> this will prompt the user to select a sheet and a cell/range. But he can't just select a sheet without telling which cell/range.

Comment: @karma hey, thanks for joining the thread. So there are two documents. One is a source, with a bunch of pre formatted data. Another is a destination, that has restricted editing. If i paste using the range format, it pastes incorrectly and user privlages wont let me unhide rows to fix a paste. One more ante, is i need the user to select which excel file is the destination. (There are mutliple types of  the same formatted destination excel sheet so its imparitive that they select the right one.)

Comment: If you integrate the below with @karma 's `application.inputbox("select a range", Type:=8)` then you could really be cooking with fire.

Comment: @Dmrive, I'm sorry I still unable to understand what exactly you want. One thing for sure, I know that you want (A) the user select a particular Excel file to be opened. So you do the code to prompt the explorer to the user so he can browse the file and choose the file. Now what next ? (B) Do you also want the user to select the range to be copied on Source.xlsm workbook? (C) Do you also want the user to select **the sheet and the cell/range** to be pasted on that particular workbook he chose to open on point-A ?

Comment: Hey Karma, I would check the marked solution. Essentially, I used that, then after a user selects it, dumps the data in preselected ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on making the user identify the correct workbook/worksheet, then you can try something like this:

```
Sub Main_Sub()

    Dim SourceWB As Workbook
    Set SourceWB = ManualSelectWorkbook
    
    ' >>> Following line are only to demonstrate
    '     selected workbook is saved as "SourceWB"
        Debug.Print SourceWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value
        SourceWB.Activate

End Sub
Function ManualSelectWorkbook() As Workbook

    ' > Variables
    Dim WB As Workbook          'Possible Destination Workbook
    Dim Dict As Object          'Dictionary of workbook names
    Dim PromptText As String    'Inputbox Text Prompt
    Dim WBselected As Integer   'Index number of selected workbook
    Dim I As Integer            'Iterations
    
    ' > Variable Prep
    I = 1
    PromptText = ""
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' > Store names of each open workbook
    For Each WB In Application.Workbooks
        Dict.Add I, WB.Name
        PromptText = PromptText & "#" & I & " = " & WB.Name & vbCrLf
        I = I + 1
    Next WB
    
    ' > Ask user which workbook they wish to use
    WBselected = InputBox("Please indicate which workbook you would like this data copied to:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        PromptText & vbCrLf & _
        "Must be integer.", "Workbook Selection", "1")
        
    ' > Set Function = selected workbook
    'Debug.Print Dict(WBselected)
    Set ManualSelectWorkbook = Workbooks(Dict(WBselected))
    
    ' > Clear dictionary
    Dict.RemoveAll
    
End Function
```

[image: MsgBox Example]

You can even do the exact same thing inside the selected workbook to identify the correct worksheet.

-

On the otherhand, if you know the partial name of the output workbook, you can use something like this:

```
Sub ExampleSub()

    'Sub to initiate function
    AlternateEnding.Activate

End Sub

Function AlternateEnding() As Workbook
    
    Dim WB As Workbook
    
    For Each WB In Application.Workbooks
        If WB.Name Like "*Insert partial workbook name*" Then '<<< Must Leave asterixes. 
            AlternateEnding = WB
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next WB
    
End Function
```

Comment: This is it. You are amazing! I found a way to input it. Essencially, the reason why I needed to identify which one is which is because there are 3-5 of the same formatted documents with the same name. I'll post the final code when I am finalizing it. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey Cameron, how would I reference the workbook then in my main Sub? Would i just use the variable name and set it as the active wb?

Comment: I've edited the top code a little to make it more clear. I've renamed the sub `"Main_Sub"`, and edited the code to show how you could use the WB selection function to save your selected workbook as a `workbook` variable, then reference it at any point later.